# data within script tags that I need to export to a node post rout

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have some code using the google maps API and I am using the direction service to calculate the time it tasks to drive between two points the problem is that it returns the time inside of a script tag and I am trying to send the data to a Mongo database through the node. In summary, is there any way to export data to the node without a form.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can send data using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)